# Size of Grid is NaN, wpf

Tags: wpf, grid

I want to get size of Grid, but I get NaN..
Here is the xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPFHCI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPFHCI"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="1024" MinHeight="700" MinWidth="1024">
    <Grid Background="#FFEEEEEE">
 
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollOnGrid" Margin="280 55 10 10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <!--<Grid Name="MCGrid" Margin="100 100 50 50">
            </Grid>-->
            <Grid Width="Auto" Margin="10 10 10 10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="MCGrid">
                <!-- <Grid x:Name="MCGrid"/> HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/> -->
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid> 
</Window>
```

And here is the code for get grid size, but I always get NaN.. Any idea for solution?

```
int width = MCGrid.Width;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MCGrid.ActualWidth` to get the width of `Grid`.

```
double width = MCGrid.ActualWidth;
```